# Getting DbSet from consoleApp connected to PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, linq, console-application

How to get data from database? (generic)

when i try to call GetCollection method

```
var collection = _database.GetCollection<ImportHistory>(nameof(ImportHistory));
```

i get following error on line with code:
`var xxx = x.ToList();`

System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a DbSet for 'ConnectorDbMigrations.Models.Ruian.ImportHistory' because this type is not included in the model for the context. However the model contains an entity type with the same name in a different namespace: 'ConnectorDbMigrations.Models.Ruian.ImportHistory'.

`var x = ruianDbContext.Set<TDocument>(name);`

[image: EF is not configured?]

```
public class DocumentDatabase : IDocumentDatabase
    {
        private readonly RuianDbContext ruianDbContext;
        private readonly DbContext dbContext;

        public DocumentDatabase(
            RuianDbContext ruianDbContext,
            DbContext dbContext)
        {
            this.ruianDbContext = ruianDbContext;
            this.dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        IEnumerable<TDocument> IDocumentDatabase.GetCollection<TDocument>(string name)
        {
            var x = ruianDbContext.Set<TDocument>(name);

            var xxx = x.ToList();
            return x;
        }
    }
```

DbContext

```
public class RuianDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected readonly IConfiguration _configuration;


    public RuianDbContext(
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }


    public virtual DbSet<ImportHistory> ImportHistory { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(_configuration.GetConnectionString("PostgreSQL"));
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ImportHistory>().ToTable("ImportHistory");
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using ConnectorDbMigrations.Data;
using ConnectorDbMigrations.DataProviders;
using ConnectorDbMigrations.Models.Ruian;
using ConnectorDbMigrations.Repository;
using ConnectorDbMigrations.Services;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
                config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true);
                if (args != null) config.AddCommandLine(args);
            })
            .ConfigureServices((hostingContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddScoped<IDocumentDatabase, DocumentDatabase>();
                services.AddScoped<RuianDbContext>();
                services.AddDbContext<RuianDbContext>();
                services.AddDbContext<DbContext>();
                AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);

                
            })
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
            {
                logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration);
                logging.AddConsole();
            });    
        await builder.RunConsoleAsync();
    }
}
```

ImportHistory.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace ConnectorDbMigrations.Models.Ruian;

public class ImportHistory : IDocument
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Id { get; set; } = null!;

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public DateTimeOffset? Timestamp { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Datum spuštění importu.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime ImportDate { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Zdroj dat od...
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime? DataFrom { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Zdroj dat do...
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime DataTo { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Příznak, jestli jde o úplný import.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsFullImport { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Doba běhu importu.
    /// </summary>
    public double RunTimeSeconds { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to look in the database, there is a table "ImportHistory" and there is even a record in it.
in the peephole at variable x, there is an ImportHistory table including the necessary data in the dbcontext property.

Comment: Can you please post a full [mre] somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a schema for the `ImportHistory` table:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ImportHistory>().ToTable("ImportHistory", schema: "YOR_SCHEMA_GOES_HERE");
```

You can do the same using a special attribute without the Fluent API:

```
[Table("ImportHistory", Schema = "public")]
public class ImportHistory : IDocument
{
// properties go below...
}
```

In the snippet above, I have set a `public` schema for the `ImportHistory` table.